# Stuck on elementary proof on completeness of $W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R})$ as Hilbert Space

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}):=X$ be the space of continuous functions $f$ such that $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and there exists $f'\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ such that

$$
f(b)-f(a)=\int_a^b f'(t)\,dt
$$

for every $a\le b$. I want to show that $X$ is Hilbert space with respect to the IP

$$
\langle f,h\rangle=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(t)h(t)+f'(t)h'(t) \,dt
$$

Using the fact that

$$
||f||_{\infty}\le 2^{-\frac{1}{2}} ||f||_{1,2}
$$

where $||\cdot||_{1,2}$ is norm induced by IP.

---

So if $f_n$ is Cauchy on $X$, then it automatically means it is Cauchy with respect to $\infty$ norm, and that means $f_n$ converges uniformly to a continuous function $f$.

Further, since being Cauchy on $X$ implies being Cauchy with respect to $L^2$ norm, it follows that $f_n\to g$ in $L^2$ (by completeness of $L^2$) for some $g\in L^2$, but then we know that there is a subsequence $f_{n_k} \to g$ almost surely, and with pointwise uniform convergence of $f_n$ to $f$ this implies

$$
f_n\to f \in L^2
$$

and $f$ is also continuous. Clearly, similar argument shows that $f'\to h\in L^2$, but I'm having a bit of trouble with showing that $L^2$ limit of $f'$ satisfies the condition required for $f$ to be in $X$. Namely, I expect

$$
f(b)-f(a)=\int_{a}^b h(t)\,dt 
$$

for all $a\le b$, but how do we deduce this?

*Reminder*: After some google search on the topic completeness of Sobolev spaces and stuff, I've found many articles describing this space (probably equivalent but) in different forms - which didn't make much sense to me. This was only an exercise on theory of Hilbert Spaces, and not a study of Sobolev spaces itself, so I'd appreciate if you could explain in terms of elementary stuff and possibly only using definition given above. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost done. Since $f_n\to f$ pointwise, and $f_n'\to h$ in $L^2$, it follows that for every $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$f(b)-f(a)= \lim_{n\to\infty}(f_n(b)-f_n(a)) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_a^b f_n'(t)\,dt = \int_a^b h(t)\,dt $$
The last step here is based on the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$\int_a^b |f_n'(t)-h(t)|\,dt \le (b-a)^{1/2}\left(\int_a^b |f_n'(t)-h(t)|^2\,dt\right)^{1/2} \to 0$$